# Did you install mysqlclient?

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

I have read every single post and googled for the last 4 hours to try to find a solution to this error.

I am not running virtual environment, this server is just for django. 

Server: Ubuntu 16.04

python: 3.5.2

I am getting this error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

trying to install mysqlclient

```
sudo -H pip3 install mysqlclient
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (1.3.12)
```

using ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install -y python3-mysqldb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3-mysqldb is already the newest version (1.3.7-1build2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: **I am not running virtual environment**

Comment: Please show the full traceback. How are you running Django?

Comment: Note that even if "this server is just for django", it's still a good idea to use a virtualenv to shield you from system python packages changes.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VW8bu1JK 
for start logs

Comment: apparently Pillow and MYSQLclient will not play together in django

Answer (score 23):

MySQL client did not install properly. For that this module did not find. So why it returned this error message. Bellow my practical codes, that I solved this problem. Hopefully might your.

Go to your command terminal and type [Based on Operating System(Windows, Mac Os, Linux)]

You may upgrade setuptools package If not updated

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then install python mysql

```
pip install pymysql
```

Then edit the **init**.py file in project root directory (where settings.py file located)

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Edit the settings.py file on root directory:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'database name',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',  // If localhost
        'PORT': '3306',  // your database running port
    }
}
```

That's it. I hope, I shall be able to little help you. If any problem, please comments me.

Comment: See at [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048285/931883) if want to use mysqlclient.

Comment: Perfect solution, for the fail of compilation with ARM

Comment: this works as well for my RPM (RHEL 9.2, Rocky 9.2, Leap 15.4) environment using the mozilla guide [Setting up a Django development environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment).

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and here is a fast and easy solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

some time you got this type error when trying to install the mysqlclient

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: /home/alen/Desktop/django_admin/admindashboard/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-0_fdpfs5/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-0_fdpfs5/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-0_fdpfs5/mysqlclient/pip-egg-info
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-0_fdpfs5/mysqlclient/
Complete output (12 lines):
/bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
/bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-0_fdpfs5/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
  File "/tmp/pip-install-0_fdpfs5/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 65, in get_config
    libs = mysql_config("libs")
  File "/tmp/pip-install-0_fdpfs5/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
    raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
OSError: mysql_config not found
----------------------------------------ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

you installed the pymysql but no effect in there then plese try the following command

```
     sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential #for debin
```

after install this then run

```
 pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: build-essential is missing for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's very dummy but this works for me!
i used virtualenv .
created a .venv file and activate it.absolutely installing every package in it.
but then i deactivate the virtualenv and installed mysqlclient directly into OS.
now works fine.i don't know why python, django can not find mysqlclient from virtualenv environment.

Answer (score 0):

on console type -> pip install mysql-python

```
myengine=''
mydb=''
myuser=''
mypass=''
myhost= '' 
myport = ''

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': myengine,
    'NAME': mydb,
    'USER': myuser,
    'PASSWORD': mypass,
    'HOST': myhost,
    'PORT': myport
   }
  }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pymysql
```

Then, edit the **init**.py file in your project origin dir(the same as settings.py)

add:

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

This should work.